# Make part of a list as a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `lst`

```
lst = ['Hi', 'Hello', '4', '71.5', '', '71.5', '', '68.1', '', '69', '', '69.4', '', '69.4', '', '70.3', '73.3', '']
```

I want to make a new list by part of the original list: after the third element, all others are in a list ignoring empty strings.

```
lst = ['Hi', 'Hello', '4', [71.5, 68.1, 69.0, 69.4, 69.4, 70.3, 73.3]]
```

I was trying `(lst[2:]).split()` after the third element ignores empty strings and put them in the list as numbers.

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
lst = ['Hi', 'Hello', '4', '71.5', '', '71.5', '', '68.1', '', '69', '', '69.4', '', '69.4', '', '70.3', '73.3', '']

result = lst[:3] + [[float(e) for e in lst[3:] if e]]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Hi', 'Hello', '4', [71.5, 71.5, 68.1, 69.0, 69.4, 69.4, 70.3, 73.3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or `filter` + `map` (kind of long):

```
lst = lst[:3]+[list(filter(lambda i: type(i)==float,map(lambda x: float(x) if x else x,lst[3:])))]
```

Now:

```
print(lst)
```

Is:

```
['Hi', 'Hello', '4', [71.5, 71.5, 68.1, 69.0, 69.4, 69.4, 70.3, 73.3]]
```